# ¿ Una tabla hija debe llevar la llave primaria de la tabla padre?

Tags: base-de-datos

Tengo una base datos donde la tabla usuarios hereda de la tabla persona y otra tabla empleados que también hereda de usuarios , a la vez los usuarios pueden crear empleados.
Soy principiante en Base Datos, recuerdo en mis clases nos decian que las tablas de herencia no deberían llevar llave primaria, que tan cierto es esto? Yo personalmente considero que las tablas hijo si deberian llevar llave primaria. Alguien me puede explicar mejor porfavor.---1 ¿Las tablas hijas deberian llevar llave primaria o simplemente heredar la llave primaria del padre (que es PERSONA)?
---2) ¿En que afectaría que no tenga llave primaria las tablas hijo?
---3) ¿Por ultimo es correcto afirmar que todas las tablas deben tener su llave primaria?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Depende la tabla que estés haciendo, si es una tabla que requiera tener un campo esencialmente único, entonces hazlo, en todo caso usa un auto-incremental simplemente. Igual siempre debes tener la FK en la tabla hijo.

Comment: Parece que estas en un caso isA (Es un) este tipo de casos hay que analizarlo según tu caso. Si es así el id debería ser el mismo que el de la tabla principal. Pero si es una relación distinta puede necesitar su propia clave

Answer (score -1):

La relación entre la tabla padre e hija debe ser 1 a 1, entre otras cosas...

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/407931)